# How to set color for all textviews in row in listadapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

i have created a listadapter like the picture below and populate the textviews from hashmap like this

```
          HashMap<String, String> kursiShitje = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                kursiShitje.put("text_1", "Shitje");
                JSONObject c = values.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_SELL);
                kursiShitje.put("text_" + (i + 2), name);
            }
```

Here is the listadapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, kursiKembimit,
                R.layout.list_rows, new String[]{"text_1", "text_2", "text_3", "text_4", "text_5", "text_6", "text_7"},
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4, R.id.text5, R.id.text6, R.id.text7}) {
```

list_rows.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rows"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text7"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The question is on how do i set a unique text color for each row in the list. I can set color for all the textviews with overriding getView but i want to set unique color for each row. I cant figure out how to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: you must use your custom adapter !!

Comment: i mean baseadapter or arrayadapter

Comment: show `R.layout.list_rows` this xml file?

Comment: @SohailZahid added R.layout.list_rows

Comment: @VishalPatoliya do u have any proper example for what im trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What color you set for each `textView` in this layout will be the same color in rows.

You have set the `White color` for all text view set different colors.

try diffrernt color here   `android:textColor="@color/BLUE"` and check out the result.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```

Comment: I override the list_rows view and set the color like this
`TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                   text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));` 
For all textviews.

Comment: @Aldo yes that is also great option.so is your issue fixed?if my post help a little please vote up and tick marks thanks.

Comment: i want to use different color for each row created, the hashmap is 1 of 3 hashmaps i have build to populate data.
now currently i only can set one color for all the rows and textviews.